# REST api with HttpClient but unknown JSON response

Tags: json, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using the WebApi httpclient to build up a .net api library for use against a REST webservice.

The rest service returns JSON.

Problem i am having is that for one request, it is possible that i get diffrent JSON formats back.

If the query was successful, I get back a JSON array which I have made a strong c# type to hold it.

Using the ReadAsAsync< T > method to get it out of the content.

If the request had a bad api key in or another error happens, the rest service returns a JSON object with some properties like status=error and an explanation message etc.

I cant then just use the ReadAsAsync< T > method as I dont know what format is comming back. I don't know much about the JSON linq library but is there a way I can put the JSON response into some JSON holder object and then check if there is a status=error in it and then use the correct deserialization to my strong type.

I seem to be able to store it in a JRaw object but don't know where to go from here.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> If the request had a bad api key in or another error happens, the rest service returns a JSON object with some properties like status=error and an explanation message etc.

In this case, the status code returned will not be successful.  You can do a check on the status code and then deserialize your response content appropriately:

```
        if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
           // Deserialize your JSON array
        }
        else
        {
           // Deserialize the error
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use error handling in this case

```
try
{
      //Deserialize your JSON Array..this will throw an exception in case of type mismatch
}
catch(Exception e)
{
     //Deserialize your JSON object which will give you Error code or message
}
```